# Algolia Disable Prefix on attributes when using Magento extension

Tags: magento, algolia

I am using the Algolia Magento extension to index products in a Magento store.

I've disabled *typo tolerance* for the **SKU** attribute in the Algolia dashboard (under Ranking). However, I don't see any way of disabling prefix matching for the SKU attribute. Is it possible to do this without modifying the underlying query (see https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters/#disableprefixonattributes)?

Comment: Try to re-index algolia from magento and check it, actually when you change configuration of algolia then must re-index.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

As for now the `disablePrefixOnAttributes` setting can be set only programmatically via [any Algolia API client](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/default/settings/#set-settings).

Magento extension currently doesn't offer any UI option on how to set this setting. The best way how to do it is to hook your code to [`algolia_products_index_before_set_settings` custom event](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/master/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Helper/Entity/Producthelper.php#L279) and enrich the settings variable with `disablePrefixOnAttributes` setting.

Currently we are working on [a new feature](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/issues/763) which will allow you to set this kind of extra settings directly from Algolia configuration in Magento. However we don't have any release ETA for this one for now.